# createDataFrame() returning a list instead of DataFrame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark 1.5.1. On startup I have `HiveContext` available as `sqlContext` but set

```
sqlContext2 = SQLContext(sc)
```

I create a pipelined RDD by parsing a list of strings to JSON

```py
data = points.map(lambda line: json.loads(line))
```

I then try to convert this into a dataframe using

```py
DF = sqlContext2.createDataFrame(data).collect()
```

This runs perfectly, but then when i run `type(DF)` it says that it is a list.

How is this possible? How is a list coming out of a `createDataFrame()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you apply `collect()` on a DataFrame, it return a list that contains all of the elements (Rows) in this DataFrame.

if you want just a DatFrame, `df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)` is enough.

There is no need for `sqlContext2` here.

Comment: thanks! it was the collect() that was ruining it. I had to use sqlContext2 in the end because Hive seems to be not working on virtual machine I am running.
df = sqlContext2.createDataFrame(data,['var1','var2']) 
only with that end bracket did i get it to pick up the schema (even though it had more variables.
anyway cheers for the solution.